# Transformar eixo y em porcentagem

Tags: porcentagem, barplot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Escrevi o seguinte código que me gera o seguinte gráfico com os valores absolutos no eixo y. Gostaria de saber como transformar o Eixo y para porcentagem para diminuir o efeito da amostragem no gráfico

ofeiporesc <- xtabs(~ouviu.falar.de.ei + escolaridade, data = dados)

```
barplot(ofeiporesc, 
        beside = TRUE, 
        xlab = "Escolaridade", 
        ylab = "Frequência absoluta", 
        col = cores, 
        main = "Ouviu falar de espécies invasoras?",
        ylim = c(0, 250))

legend("topleft", 
       legend = levels(dados$ouviu.falar.de.ei), 
       fill = cores,
       bty = "n")
```

Comment: Você quer normalizar os dados? Que tecnologia/programa/linguagem está utilizando?

Comment: Basicamente você tem que contar todos os dados e dividir cada frequência pelo número total de dados, e se quiser, multiplicar por 100.

Comment: Ola Edney, queria que o eixo y ficasse em porcentagem para que por exemplo: uma barra de 50% na escolaridade "ensino medio" fique do mesmo tamanho que uma barra 50% na escolaridade "pos graduacao", apesar de a amostragem ser diferente. Estou utilizando a linguagem R

Comment: Não sei R especificamente, se por acaso não encontrar um comando que faz isso recomendo tratar os dados antes de plotar. Isso é fácil de fazer, se for poucos dados você faz isso no excel mesmo.